# In graphql java kickstart how to extract raw query being fired

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java, graphql-java-tools

In query resolver can i extract the raw query or list of fields/sub-objects which are getting returned in response? I need to apply some logic based on the attributes being returned in response.

Comment: The actual query is usually in the the 4th parameter to the resolver "info"